# Subscribe to /tf for position?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all

I used the diffDrive_plugin and publish the position data onto the rostopic "\tf".
using

```
           rostopic echo tf
```

I got:

```
transforms: 

header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 22
    nsecs: 164000000
  frame_id: /odom
child_frame_id: /base_footprint
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: -0.0680770173496
    y: 0.00835326625379
    z: -0.00216662328182
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: -0.172377366036
    w: 0.985030986151
```

The question is how to use the tf::TransformListener listener to lookup and store such value? thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64108/subscribe-to-/tf--for-position?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Follow this link http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29 or go through tf_echo source code, copy it in a new file and then use it. To store it u can data type "pose" or "stamped pose" or there are some data types specifically for transforms.

Hope it helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3